# ngInit not working asynchronously(with $q promise)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

Edit:
Plunker is working, actual code isn't:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5oVWGCVeuTwTARhZDVMl?p=preview

The service is contains typical getter\setter stuff, beside that, it functions fine, so I didn't post it's code to avoid TLDR.

TLDR version: trying to ng-init a value fetched with AJAX into the ngModel of the text-area, the request resolves with the correct value, but the textarea remain empty.

parent controller function(talks to the service):

```
$scope.model.getRandomStatus = function(){
    var deffered = $q.defer();
var cid = authService.getCompanyId();

var suggestions = companyService.getStatusSuggestions(cid);
if(suggestions && suggestions.length > 0){
        deffered.resolve(suggestions[Math.floor(Math.random(suggestions.length) + 1)].message);
        return deffered.promise;//we already have a status text, great!
    }

    //no status, we'll have to load the status choices from the API
    companyService.loadStatusSuggestions(cid).then(function(data){
        companyService.setStatusSuggestions(cid, data.data);
        var result = data.data[Math.floor(Math.random(data.data.length) + 1)];
        deffered.resolve(result.message);   
    },
    function(data){
        _root.inProgress = false;
        deffered.resolve('');
        //failed to fetch suggestions, will try again the next time the compnay data is reuqired
    });
    return deffered.promise;
}
```

child controller:

```
.controller('shareCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.layout.toggleStatusSuggestion = function(){
         $scope.model.getRandomStatus().then(function(data){
            console.log(data);//logs out the correct text
            //$scope.model.formData.shareStatus = data;//also tried this, no luck
            return data.message;
         });
    $scope.model.formData.shareStatus = $scope.layout.toggleStatusSuggestion();//Newly edited
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="shareContainer" data-ng-controller="shareCtrl">
 <textarea class="textAreaExtend" name="shareStatus" data-ng-model="model.formData.shareStatus" data-ng-init="model.formData.shareStatus = layout.toggleStatusSuggestion()" cols="4"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: can just set the value within `then()` in controller instead of using `ng-init`. Nothing is returned from your `toggleStatusSuggestion ` method

Comment: Well, I also tried the above line in the controller(marked as '//newly edited').
No luck so far.
Thank for the prompt response!

Comment: I am now working on a plunk for you to experiment with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are wanting is :

```
$scope.model.getRandomStatus().then(function(data){            
            $scope.model.formData.shareStatus = data.message;

});
```

Returning something from within `then` does not return anything from the function wrapping it and therefore does nothing

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/5oVWGCVeuTwTARhZDVMl?p=preview

here is is working fiddle that I've created, I just cannot put my finger on what is wrong with my code(the actual one)

Comment: you haven't tried my suggestion. Logic is wrong trying to return something from within `then()` and since it is being done aysnch, you have to set any necessary values within `then`. Your code will fire before `then` occurs

Comment: Ok, solved the problem, I had a custom validation directive that was breaking the whole thing.

with $parsers and $formatters, but I guess that you answer is good for anyone who will look this up, so for that matter it is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had a custom validation directive that was watching the changes in the model via $formatters, and limting it to 80 chars(twitter), it was failing silently as I didn't expect to progmatically insert invalid values into my forms, very stupid, but could happen to anyone.
Had to make some changes to it, so it's worth to remember in case it happens to anyone else.